# Sending a byte array to PHP script as POST in Blackberry

Tags: arrays, blackberry, post, byte

My Blackberry application has to send a byte array (audio) to my PHP script via POST.

Comment: A visit to the post office didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will help you take a look

it is available java and bb also

posting date using "UrlEncodedPostData "

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/question-about-sending-by-post-and-using-UrlEncodedPostData/m-p/230148#M35577

Comment: I got a working script @ http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=884. Hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending binary data, you probably need a multipart post request. You don't want your content to be URL-Encoded.

This is an example (generic J2ME, works on Blackberry too):

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

The MultipartPostData class also uses URL-Encoding, and is not designed to handle binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the array, you might want to do what I'm attempting - that is to send it base64 encoded.